# MATLAB: Permanently set "Text Update Function" for Data Cursor in figures

Tags: matlab, user-interface, customization, figure

**Problem:** I use MATLAB for science, and I often need more than 4 significant digits. Every time I use `Data Cursor` in a figure's GUI, I need to manually right-click on the point, `Select Text Update Function...` or `Edit Text Update Function...`, and navigate to the folder where I saved the function whose callback prints more than 4 (e.g. 8) significant figures. This is annoying and there should be a way to automatically change this.

**Ideal answer:** I want this done permanently for all figures, e.g. in a function that changes default settings in my `startup.m` file.

**Good enough answer:** I want a wrapped function to which I give the figure handle and it fixes this for me.

I humbly await SO's infinite wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The permanent solution**

would be, to edit the `default_getDatatipText.m` function.
You can find it in:

```
C:\...\MATLAB\R20xxx\toolbox\matlab\graphics\@graphics\@datacursor
```

There you will find the line:

```
DEFAULT_DIGITS = 4;  % Display 4 digits of x,y position
```

Edit it as desired, you can't do much harm, but make a backup before if you want.

**Alternative solution:**

There is also the possibility of **custom data tips**: [Tutorial at Matlab Central](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2011/10/19/tutorial-how-to-make-a-custom-data-tip-in-matlab/)

It could finally look like this:

[image]

(additional text outside data-tips was post-processed)

---

And as you're talking about precision. The data-tip always snaps to the closest data-point. **It doesn't show interpolated data at the clicked position.**

Comment: Bonus points: A solution that works only for my user, not all users.

Comment: Well, then you could just use the custom datatips as shown in the tutorial. Copy&Paste the original functions to you workspace which is probably located at your windows user profile, and add everything as you wish. It could then look like in my picture. I can't provide code unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The permanent answer given by thewaywewalk doesn't work anymore in R2015a, and probably later ones. So here I share my solution for both the temporary and permanent solution

**Temporary solution (for a single figure):**

The following function contains the update function as a nested function. Call `datacursorextra` to apply it to the current figure, or `datacursorextra(fig)` to apply it to some figure `fig`.

```
function datacursorextra(fig)
    % Use current figure as default
    if nargin<1
        fig = gcf;
    end

    % Get the figure's datacursormode, and set the update function
    h = datacursormode(fig);
    set(h,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)

    % The actual update function
    function txt = myupdatefcn(~,event)
        % Short-hand to write X, Y and if available Z, with 10 digit precision:
        lbl = 'XYZ';
        txt = arrayfun(@(s,g)sprintf('%s: %.10g',s,g), lbl(1:length(event.Position)), event.Position,'uniformoutput',false);

        % If a DataIndex is available, show that also:
        info = getCursorInfo(h);
        if isfield(info,'DataIndex')
            txt{end+1} = sprintf('Index: %d', info.DataIndex);
        end
    end
end
```

**Permanent solution (apply to all figures by default):**

I have not found a way to set a default `UpdateFcn` for the data cursor, but it is possible to add some code which will be called every time a new figure is created. Add the following line to your `startup.m`:

```
set(0,'defaultFigureCreateFcn',@(s,e)datacursorextra(s))
```

and make sure the `datacursorextra` function given above is available in your Matlab path.

Answer (score 0):

@caspar's solution works very well.
You can also update the txt{} part of the solution with

```
    if isfield(info,'DataIndex')
       DataIndex = [info.DataIndex];
       txt{end+1} = sprintf('Index: %d\n', DataIndex(1));
    end
```

This will enable you to update the Index field when you have multiple pointers in the same figure.